# IONIC 2 Hot Deploy

Tags: android, angular, ionic2

I am using the live update /deploy feature of IONIC 2.
It all works perfectly. But when the app is updating itself the user sees a white screen for 3-5 seconds. Is there a way to disable the white screen or  show a splash screen while the update is happening?

Also i get this error, After shows a white screen.

> Application Error  The connection to the server was
>   unsuccessful.(file:/data/data/com.xxx.xxx/app_hsj7498ke4-0292-2211-u29/index.html)

Comment: I've been using code push and it basically installs when you resume and then updates when you reopen the app again. I guess you need a similar approach. Separate install & update.

Comment: It will automatically get restart, Once update is done. It shows a white screen when its getting restart. How to avoid that white screen? or Is there a way to close and reopen the app, Once update is done?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is very doable:

First, make sure you have [ionic native splash screen](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/splash-screen/) as part of your project.

Make sure you inject it where you want to use it:

```
constructor(
    private deploy: Deploy,
    private splashScreen: SplashScreen,
) {}
```

Then, before calling `this.deploy.load();` just show the splash screen. For example, here's my implementation:

```
return this.deploy.download()
    .then(() => {
        return this.deploy.extract();
    })
    .then(() => {
        this.splashScreen.show();
        this.deploy.load();
    });
```

This will show your splash screen before re-loading the app.